# jQuery width toggle moves the div to the left

Tags: jquery, width, toggle

I have this script http://jsfiddle.net/Z8cuz/2/
Code:

```
$('.list').hide();
$('.close').hide();
var widthVal = false;
$('#left').click(function () {
    if (widthVal == false) {
        $('#middle').hide('fade', 300);
        $('#right').hide('fade', 300, function () {
            $('#left').find('.list').show();
            $('#left').find('.close').show();
            $('#left').animate({
                width: "96%",
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
        });
        widthVal == true;
    }
});
$('#middle').click(function () {
    if (widthVal == false) {
        $('#left').hide('fade', 300);
        $('#right').hide('fade', 300, function () {
            $('#middle').find('.list').show();
            $('#middle').find('.close').show();
            $('#middle').animate({
                width: "96%",
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
        });
        widthVal == true;
    }
});
$('#right').click(function () {
    if (widthVal == false) {
        $('#left').hide('fade', 300);
        $('#middle').hide('fade', 300, function () {
            $('#right').find('.list').show();
            $('#right').find('.close').show();
            $('#right').animate({
                width: "96%",
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
        });
        widthVal == true;
    }
});
$('.close').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().animate({
        width: "30%",
        opacity: 1
    }, 1500, function(){
    widthVal == false;
    $('#left').show('fade', 600);
    $('#middle').show('fade',600);
    $('#right').show('fade', 600);
    $('.list').hide();
    $('.close').hide();
    });
});
```

When I click the left box, it works ok, but when I click the middle or the right one, it goes left, then changes its width. I want it to keep the position and change the width.

Answer (score 1):

use this function n yr problem will be solved

```
function sorted(obj){
  var clonedObj = obj.clone();
  obj.remove();
  $('#container').prepend(clonedObj);
}
```

here is [live example](http://jsbin.com/apeloDe/39/edit)

Answer (score 0):

As an option you could reduce the width in the sides. check the code I create a fiddle only for the #middle div, to give you an idea. http://jsfiddle.net/7a7n2/
I did as an example the middle one.

```
$('#middle').click(function () {
        if (widthVal == false) {
            $('#left').animate({opacity:'0'},300);
            $('#left').animate({width:'0'},1000);
            $('#right').hide('fade', 300, function () {

                $('#middle').find('.list').show();
                $('#middle').find('.close').show();
                $('#middle').animate({
                    width: "96%",
                    opacity: 1
                }, 1000);
            });
            widthVal == true;
        }
    });
```